# Storing custom dashboard widget options in wordpress

Tags: widgets, dashboard

I am using the [Codex example](http://codex.wordpress.org/Example_Dashboard_Widget) to build a custom widget. The specific example seems to be working fine until you click configure and change options values. After you click submit, changes are not saved. Is anyone having the same problem with the specific example? I am trying to build a custom widget using this as an example.

Comment: Ok fixed. In widget-config.php there is no check if the form has been submitted, so every time you load configuration it updates with empty values or keeps default ones. Add this check if (!empty($_POST))  before updating options values and display stored value of number-input. <input type="text" name="number" value="<?php echo self::get_dashboard_widget_option(self::wid, 'example_number'); ?>"  />*

Comment: Please add that comment as a real answer in the "Answer" box below and mark it "Accepted".

Comment: I tried but I can't...I don't have that much reputation to do that.

Comment: [You need a total Rep of 1 to answer a question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/privileges/create-posts).

Comment: @s_ha_dum Users with less than 10 reputation can't answer their own question for 8 hours after asking. You can answer in 6 hours. Until then please use comments, or edit your question instead.

Comment: Ok. You are running into that timer. Got it. @RRG  : now you have >10

Answer (score 2):

<sup>Solution [pulled from OP](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/revisions/103247/3).</sup>

Ok fixed. In `widget-config.php` there is no check if the form has been submitted, so every time you load configuration it updates with empty values or keeps default ones. Add this check `if (!empty($_POST))` before updating options values and display stored value of number-input:

```
<input type="text" name="number" value="<?php echo self::get_dashboard_widget_option(self::wid, 'example_number'); ?>" />
```

Comment: The examples in the codex should be updated with this fix.